# what owner and permissions on www/html folder

Tags: html, web, permissions, chmod, owner

I recently installed vsftpd on my Ubuntu server 14.04. I'm now trying to use filezilla to transfer files to my www/html folder but i get "550 permission denied". The permissions is currently set to 755, and the owner of the folder is root. I used this guide when configuring vsftpd: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-on-ubuntu-12-04
What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing the owner of the folder to your FTP user:

```
sudo chown -R name-of-your-ftp-user www/html
```

Comment: What are the permissions on the directory containing `www`?

Comment: Starting in `/`, is there any folder in the chain that "everyone" has no read access to?

Comment: every folder to html has 755 as permissons.

Comment: And you actually did set `write_enable=YES` in the config and restart vsftpd afterwards?